# how to make a method which can change text property of any text box from any thread in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

I am not a really good C# programmer. I am used to C but not C#.

I know that from a thread other than UI thread we cannot change the property of textbox and labels.

So after trying few different ways I am using this method all the time:

```
 item.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
            {
                item.Text = text;
            }));
```

Then after writing some code I noticed it is boring and inefficient to do this every single time, so I made a method:

```
static void change_text_from_different_thread(TextBox item, string text)
        {
            item.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
            {
                item.Text = text;
            }));

        }
```

then I tried to use this in my thread the problem is that I can't send the TextBox from the thread.

let's say this is my thread:

```
{

change_text_from_different_thread(textbox1,"Hi");

}
```

then I get this error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property

So could you tell me how I can pass the textbox?
BTW there is a chance that my invoke method is wrong or very dangerous, but I could not find a easier way. If it is really bad, please let me know. If it is okay, also let me know. If by using another method things get better and easier please do let me know as well.

It is my first time asking question, sorry if I have missed some thing. 
Thank you very much.

This is my method:

```
static void gyro_self_check_thread_function()
{
//lab lab
}
```

this is how I made a thread and start it:

```
private void Gyro_self_check_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Gyro_self_check_status_label.Text = "Status: Checking....";
            gyro_self_testing_groupBox.Update();
            _serialPort.Write(Protocal_Values.gyro_self_checking_request, 0, 2);


            Thread gyro_self_check_thread = new Thread(gyro_self_check_thread_function);
            gyro_self_check_thread.Start();

            //Thread gyro_self_check_thread = new Thread(gyro_self_check_thread);
            //gyro_self_check_thread.Start();



        }
```

Comment: Updating UI from a worker thread is in general a very questionable practice.  See BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext and the C# 5 async/await keywords for alternatives.  Make sure you don't make something you should not do easy to do.  It should hurt.

Comment: To add to what Hans is saying, the idea here is to separate your user interface logic from your business logic.  By the sounds of this question, you're trying to integrate the two tightly together.  Don't.

Comment: How would you change a textbox text, if the result should come from another thread?

Comment: I read this
http://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar
and I got an idea. But I have many small threads if I do this for all my code, it will be way longer.
I read about this TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext and I did not understand anything.
I have time limit so for now, I will just use invoke.
But I was wondering if there was a way to pass some tasks to UI thread so that it will take care of them, the next time it is being processed. the idea came to my mind when I read this "TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext".

Comment: Can anyone give a suggestion for a tutorial where TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext has been covered?

Comment: I read about async and I love it. I will try to implement it now.

Comment: I just noticed that I did not understand anything about async. A ood reference is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your thread method is also static and textbox1 is a non-static field, so it cannot be accessed from static method.

If this is the case, then you can make your thread method non-static and it should compile.

Comment: I do not know how to make a non-static thread method. Let me search and see if I can learn.

Comment: I could not find a right place to read, could you show me a good reference.

Comment: Update your question to include thread creation code and thread method, probably removing static from method modifiers would be sufficient.

Comment: It has been updated.
I tried to make a public class in my WindowsFormsApplication1. then I made a method in the class. In the class I cannot access UI components.

Comment: gyro_self_check_thread_function probably should not be static

Comment: I feel very stupid, I thought we can only have static methods for start of a thread.

Answer (score 0):

As another posted commented, this is probably an issue with static vs. non-static access.  To alleviate this problem, you might be able to write this as an extension method on TextBox:

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
     static void change_text_from_different_thread(this TextBox item, string text)
     {
         item.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
             {
                 item.Text = text;
             }));

     }
}
```

Then you call it like so:

```
textbox1.change_text_from_different_thread("Hi");
```

Comment: If his problem is indeed related to the fact that he's calling this code from a static method and `textbox1` isn't static then this change wouldn't help.

Comment: True.  I guess I was trying to address the issue of have this as a member function in multiple forms, if he made it non-static.

Comment: I just tried. Servy is right, I cannot send the textbox from a different thread.